# full disk encryption with 20.04

Tags: 20.04, encryption

I think previous versions of Ubuntu offered full disk encryption in the installation sequence. I did not see this offered in my installation dialogs for 20.04. How is FDE supposed to be implemented in 20.04?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the 20.04 installer, Full Disk Encryption requires LVM to be enabled and available in the installation steps.  This is not super straightforward, but is not very difficult to set up either.

**Note that if you Dual Boot with Windows or another OS, you cannot use Full Disk Encryption, as it will affect the Windows partitions as well.  This is a known limitation of dual booting and attempting to encrypt Ubuntu, and there's no 'automated' way to fix this currently.  ONLY use Full Disk Encryption if you do NOT intend to use anything but Ubuntu on your system.**

When you get to the installation selection of erase disk or such you'll see something like this:

[image: Installation Type]

Choose "Advanced Features" - a new box will open with advanced features.

Select LVM and Encryption like so:

[image: Advanced Features]

Hit "OK" then "Install Now" on the original screen where you selected the installation type.

This next window sets your security key for the LVM/LUKS setup:

[image: Security Key Setting]

Set your password/key for decryption and hit "Install Now".  The next window will look something like this, and you will want to hit "Continue" to install and make changes to the filesystem:

[image: disk changes]

Installation continues as normal and expected after this.

Happy FDE Encryption Fun!

Comment: Note that this method does not work if you are dual-booting with Windows.

Comment: @TorKlingberg updated answer with that tidbit,.