# Unable to enable full disk encryption when installing ubuntu

Tags: encryption

[image: Ubuntu installation]

I am trying to install ubuntu 20.04 with full disk encryption however it is not giving me the option to.
I am referring to this guide [full disk encryption with 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291268/full-disk-encryption-with-20-04) which shows that there is an installation type menu. However, as seen above my ubuntu does not give me an options and directly installs the entire OS without giving me any options or windows.

I am installing this ubuntu as a virtual machine in VMWare.

Comment: "*My ubuntu does not give me an options and directly installs the entire OS without giving me any options or windows*" suggests that you have taken an unwise shortcut or perhaps are not using the real Ubuntu Desktop installer.

Comment: I downloaded it from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop. Clicking on the big green download button at the right side of Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Comment: State EXACTLY everything you clicked and typed when you ran the installer, including how you ran it.