# Do I need to erase my database to encrypt my computer?

Tags: partitioning, encryption

I am looking to encrypt my Hard-Disk, but all the steps I found say that I have to re-install ubuntu and I do not want it. Can I do it not necessarily erasing all my data?

There are a few examples of sources that I found

https://jumpcloud.com/blog/how-to-enable-full-disk-encryption-on-an-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

[full disk encryption with 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291268/full-disk-encryption-with-20-04)

Comment: You don't necessarily have to reinstall Ubuntu -- I think it comes down to which disk you want encrypted.  You can have Ubuntu installed on an unencrypted disk and have data files on a separate partition that is encrypted.  In this case, you wouldn't need to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: The title does not match the body of the question, so it's unclear whether your question is about encryption or about a database.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enable disk encryption after installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366749/enable-disk-encryption-after-installation). Like most things, it is technically possible, but the burden to achieve it would be way worse than a reinstall. So practically, no, you can't. You should reinstall the system if you want to set up full disk encryption.

Comment: maybe u can try ecryptfs? not full disk encryption but I remember doing it post installation

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will need to erase your current disk contents to set up the LVM, required for the encryption of your operating system and user data.

Of course, before proceeding, you will make sure your backups of your personal data are up to date, so you can restore data to the newly installed system.

Comment: Can the user back the data up and then reload it later?

Comment: The user *must* (anytime and always) backup the data, in this case indeed to reload it later if desired.

Comment: So, the answer is no, they don't need to erase the database. They should back it up, reinstall, then reload it.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I will add specific reference to the need of backing up the data ;) \